How to insert text in CKEditor 5 (or other rich-text editors) composer with a userscript
So I'm trying to create an autocomplete script in Tampermonkey where it will provide suggestions via a dropdown to write to the composer in Zendesk which is a CKEditor 5 implementation.
I got everything setup except the actual part of inserting text into the editor.
This is what I do as of now that works in simple sites but not in Zendesk:
const range = getSelection().getRangeAt(0); // get my caret position
range.insertNode(document.createTextNode(suggestion)); // insert the suggestion at caret position

I have zero experience with CKEditor 5 so I'm not sure how to go about it. Can someone guide me in the right direction?

The issue is likely due to how react renders the dom. You are trying to manipulate the dom dridectly and react does not automatically know about those changes. You could try using document.execCommand even tho it is deprecated: document.execCommand('insertText', false, suggestion); docs: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_execcommand.asp . There are also other options but from your snippet i can't know what would work.

What part of Zendesk are you trying to apply CKEditor code updates to ? I am assuming latest help center, is it ?

@Karun The Zendesk Tickets editor. I managed to do it, doing an implementation of what tribute.js did. basically is dispatching a beforeinput event with targetRanges property and a staticRange range in an array as a value. Then insert a text node with the insertNode method and finally dispatch an input event on the editor

i think you can simply execute the input command
editor.execute('InsertText','text to insert')

here is the documentation of the command ckEditor Docs
